# How to find the prerequisites or compiler used from a svn?

Tags: svn, compilation, ide, prerequisites

I am interested in checking out this project http://code.google.com/p/xna-shadow-warrior/ . But I don't know what version of visual studio to use. I got less errors trying visual studio for web but there are still some errors. How do you figure out how to compile and load a project from a SVN that doesn't have instructions on what compiler or ide was used? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SVN. If you don't know how to compile an open-source project, and cannot find instructions, then contact the owner or maintainer. If you cannot find that contact information, you can try the issue tracker on the project website.